# Having trouble getting google sign in to work to handle URL

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I can seem to understand the problem and I am also receiving error " Use of undeclared type "GIDSignInUIDelegate"

I have tried to reinstall pods, I have all pods needed inside pod file including "GoogleSignIn"

I can't seem to find anything online about the Extra argument either.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID

        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController())
        navController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        window?.rootViewController = navController

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                     annotation: [:])
    }
```

I receive error:

> Extra Argument 'sourceApplication'

in call beside:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: [:])
}
```

Answer (score 14):

> I can seem to understand the problem and I am also receiving error "
>   Use of undeclared type "GIDSignInUIDelegate"
>
> 2019-08-14 -- v5.0.0
>
> Changes to GIDSignIn: uiDelegate has been replaced with
>   presentingViewController.

the GIDSignInUIDelegate was required to assign self to the uiDelegate.

Since the change that to presentingViewController, you can assign self directly and don't need the delegate anymore so they removed it.

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.uiDelegate = self
```

is now

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
```

and as @efremidze indicated in his reply,

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])
```

is now simply

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
```

Comment: When I implement the same in my application, the shared instance is optional value. GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.handle(url). Why is it not the case with your code?

Answer (score 8):

You might be using v5.0.0 of GIDSignIn. They made some changes to `handle()` parameters.

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
}
```

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release

Comment: In the first link though it seems that they have not updated their documentation

Answer (score 7):

According to the [release note of Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release):

> 2019-08-14 -- v5.0.0
>
> ```
> Changes to GIDSignIn:
> uiDelegate has been replaced with presentingViewController.
> ```

To fix the errors:

**1. replace all**

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = yourDelegate
```

**with**

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = yourDelegate
```

**2. Remove all the conformances to GIDSignInUIDelegate.**

Comment: @sealroto if any of your view controllers conforms to GIDSignInUIDelegate, remove that conformance. E.g. remove `extension ViewController: GIDSignInUIDelegate` { // ... }.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today after updating pods in my project. So you can check the version of your GoogleSignIn pod in Podfile.lock and if it is 5.0.0, just replace it with 4.4.0 in Podfile (without extension). 
For that open your Podfile and add version to GoogleSignIn pod

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4.0'
```

Run command

```
pod update
```

Let me know if it helped you or not.

Comment: Instead of downgrading the pod, you just need to adjust your code to the new requirements of V5.0.0...

Comment: @Muvimotv yes, for sure. Just had to fix it quickly.